# multithreading Pool resulting in non-random numbers

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I previously asked [Repeatedly run a function in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581445/repeatedly-run-a-function-in-parallel) on how to run a function in parallel. The function that I am wanting to run has a stochastic element, where random integers are drawn.

When  I use the code in that answer it returns repeated numbers within one process (and also between runs if I add an outer loop to repeat the process). For example,

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def f(_):
    x = np.random.uniform()
    return x*x    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = 3
    p = Pool(processes)
    print(p.map(f, range(6)))
```

returns

```
[0.8484870744666029, 0.8484870744666029, 0.04019012715175054, 0.04019012715175054, 0.7741414835156634, 0.7741414835156634]
```

Another run may give

```
[0.17390735240615365, 0.17390735240615365, 0.5188673758527017, 1.308159884267618e-08, 0.09140498447418667, 0.021537291489524404]
```

It seems as if there is some internal seed that is being used -- how can I generate random numbers similar to what would be returned from `np.random.uniform(size=6)` please?

Comment: @ranifisch; Yes, I would like it to be reproducible, but the main issue just now is not to get the same random numbers drawn across the processes.

Comment: im sorry if im not understanding the question wrong, but you can do np.random.seed(0) to have same seed across all processes, or im understanding it wrong?

Comment: @ranifisch ; from the example; I would expect six different numbers, similar to the results from `np.random.uniform(size=6)` (note I just mean 6 different numbers not that they have to equal the results from `np.ranomd.unifirm` for a given seed). But I am getting the same numbers repeated (a lot of the time). The question gives a couple of instances.

Comment: oh I think this may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915177/same-output-in-different-workers-in-multiprocessing

Comment: :) ok I still can't understand the exact problem.. but seems like it's something related to seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Same output in different workers in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915177/same-output-in-different-workers-in-multiprocessing) indicates that the seed needs to be included in the function. [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) provides a way to pass multiple arguments to `Pool` -- one for the repeats and one for a list of seeds. This allows for a new seed for each process, and is reproducible.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def f(reps, seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    x = np.random.uniform()
    return x*x    

#np.random.seed(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = 3
    p = Pool(processes)
    print(p.starmap(f, zip(range(6), range(6))))
```

Where the second argument is the vector of seeds (to see change the line to `print(p.starmap(f, zip(range(0,6), np.repeat(1,6))))`)